# Unable to upgrade Azure Functions Core Tools, Exception "Cannot create instance of type 'NuGet.Versioning.VersionRange'"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, azure-functions

I'm trying to run an Azure Function. **After upgrading to .Net 6**, debugging it locally with an **updated version of Visual Studio 2022** gives me the following exception:

> A host error has occurred during startup operation
> 'dca54039-23ee-4ec2-ad9d-9deafe1b2869'. [2022-09-08T07:07:05.464Z]
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder: Cannot create instance of
> type 'NuGet.Versioning.VersionRange' because it is missing a public
> parameterless constructor.

[image: Exception when running on my machine]

**My co-workers do not get this error and it works great in production.**
The big difference we found was that they have a Core Tools Version that differs from mine.

- Mine: 4.0.3971
- Theirs: 4.0.4736

I believe the problem lies here, but besides trying to upgrade I also tried other things:

- Change to `<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>`
- Update all nuget packages for .Net 6.
- Install latest version of Core Tool as mentioned on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local

Adding the verbose flag does not get me any further and outputs the following:

[image: Verbose enabled]

Since then I've been trying to upgrade the Tools version. But here's the thing: even though func --version tells me I have 4.0.4736, the debug window still says 4.0.3971. I tried the following things:

- I uninstalled everything and then installed the MSI again from the page mentioned above.
- I ran `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4` in the Package Manager Console.
- I uninstalled and re-installed using Chocolatey
- I re-installed Visual Studio
- I did the following things in an elevated powershell window:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true
>
> changed 51 packages, and audited 52 packages in 18s found 0 vulnerabilities

> PS C:\Windows\system32> npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.4736 --unsafe-perm true
>
> changed 51 packages, and audited 52 packages in 26s found 0 vulnerabilities

> PS C:\Windows\system32> func --version
> 4.0.4736

Nothing seems to help.

Comment: Hi Jon Koeter, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered.
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: thanks. Delete the folder C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was:

- Close Visual Studio
- Delete folder C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools
- Restart Visual Studio.
- Launch Application, folder gets recreated.

As soon as I had my co-worker review this question (to make sure I didn't post any vulnerabilities) he said "Oh, that other co-worker found a solution, you should delete C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools and you're good to go"

So I did.

And it works right away.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

1. Close Visual Studio,
2. Delete folder `C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools`
3. Delete `temp` and `%temp%`
4. Restart PC
5. Restart Visual Studio.
6. Launch Application, folder gets recreated.

App started running for me and the below error got resolved:

> A host error has occurred during startup operation '8bd9dcec-3c37-4ecf-9db9-894534073cfd'.
>
> [2022-11-15T07:08:40.813Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Yep, that's in my answer. Did you mean to leave a comment?