# VS 2022 17.4.3, error running webapi project

Tags: visual-studio

error while running webapi project .Net 7.0. cleaned temp folder, reinstalled  VS. still didnt help.

earlier got this error,

[image]

then clicked -> Tools->Options->Project and Solutions->Azure Functions->Check for updates

after this, now getting below error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

below link helped.

delete azure functions folder from user\appdata

[Unable to upgrade Azure Functions Core Tools, Exception "Cannot create instance of type 'NuGet.Versioning.VersionRange'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73645163/unable-to-upgrade-azure-functions-core-tools-exception-cannot-create-instance)