# How to downgrade "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" to version 5.0.1 (Python Azure Blob Trigger)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I've been receiving an error when trying to run my blob trigger locally:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ParameterBindingData' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

I saw a solution [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/34467) that suggests downgrading "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" to version 5.0.1 may solve the problem. But I'm not exactly sure how to do that, since I don't see a specific library named that in my project. My hunch tells me it might be a apart of this package `azure-storage-blob==12.14.1` but I'm not exactly sure. I'm even specifying the version I want, I don't see how it'd suddenly break.

Any suggestions on how to do so, or other solutions I can try for the problem at hand would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

When I created a sample Azure Function Blob trigger with Python even I received the same error code:-

> [image]

> I have referred the answer by **Jon Koeter** from this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73645163/unable-to-upgrade-azure-functions-core-tools-exception-cannot-create-instance) like below:-
>
> And I deleted the Below folder from my local machine:-
>
> **C\Users\user\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools**
>
> [image]
>
> And this folder >
>
> **C\Users\AppData\Local\azure-functions-core-tools**
>
> [image]

I deleted Azure Function core tools like below:-

**C\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools**

[image]

Then I installed a new version of Azure Core tool Functions for windows 64 bit from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4,windows,csharp,portal,bash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools) and created a new blob trigger function in python and the trigger ran successfully without any error like below:-

[image]

> **Reference:-**
>
> [[BUG] Function App crashes on startup with error "Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ParameterBindingData'" · Issue #34467 ·
> Azure/azure-sdk-for-net ·
> GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/34467) **By TylerV**

Comment: Thank you this worked! And just as a heads up to other people that might come across this, my Azure Function Core Tools folder wasn't in the typical spot seen here. However, if you just go to Add or Remove Programs, you can find it there and uninstall.