# Python Azure Function expecting System.Net.Http.Formatting

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a Python Azure Function (**V2 model**) and work with **Visual Studio Code**, using Python 3.9 as an interpreter, also have 3.12 installed, but FA starts only with the Python 3.9 version.

While running the command -

```
  func host start
```

the function app almost starts but I get the following error -

```
   A host error has occurred during startup operation 'e832c327-df1a-464b-9045-e85072afd857'.
   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Not sure what am I missing, I have used "import requests" but still it doesn't seem to work.

Very striaghtforward code-

```
  import logging
  import azure.functions as func
  
  app = func.FunctionApp()
  
  @app.function_name(name="GetSettings")
  @app.route(route="company/{Id}/Settings", methods=['GET'], auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
  def GetSettings(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
 logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

 # Get ID from the route parameter
 site_id = req.route_params.get('companyId')
 logging.info(company_id)
```

Could someone suggest what am I missing?

Comment: Please share your function code

Comment: Very straightforward code, added in my question above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http: Could not load file or assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73034959/microsoft-azure-webjobs-extensions-http-could-not-load-file-or-assembly)

Comment: This one is for Visual Studio, I am using VS Code, not sure how to change versions for VS Code. But I can try.

Comment: Just noticed - the version of .NET Install Tools extension is 2.0.1 and no means to explicitly select the version of .Net SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a V2 python function and used python 3.9 as an interpreter. I am able to get the route parameter using below function code.

**function_app.py**-

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="company/{companyId}/Settings")
def HttpTriggeredFunction(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    # Get ID from the route parameter
    site_id = req.route_params.get('companyId')
    logging.info(site_id)
    
    response_message = f"Received companyId: {site_id}"

    return func.HttpResponse(
        response_message,
        status_code=200
    )
```

**host.json**-

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**requirement.txt**-

```
azure-functions
```

**launch.json**-

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9091,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**-

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "label": "func: host start",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)"
        },
        {
            "label": "pip install (functions)",
            "type": "shell",
            "osx": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**Testing**-

[image]

[image]

please use my code, you will get the results too.

Comment: No this too isn't working, I am sure something is still missing which I am not able to figure out

Comment: Can you share the error message you are getting post running my code?

Comment: [2024-01-30T09:17:16.457Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '9cd1e70d-dd82-4a69-9554-4e5c119b9bc7'.
[2024-01-30T09:17:16.460Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Comment: Could you share your requirements.txt, Launch.json and tasks.json too please?

Comment: @Shivani added the requested files in my answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This solution worked on MacOS, probably Azure Functions Core Tools version issue on my Windows machine. Selecting it as answer now.